# Is forward declaration is the only option in the C++ program?

Tags: c++

Does C++ has any other alternative to forward declaration? For example, I have a class B that uses class A.

```
class B
{
    public:
    void set_classA_val( A &b);
};

class A
{
    private:
    int example;

};
```

Is there any alternative to resolve this compilation issue rather than placing the class A above class B? Do we have any other alternative? Is forward declaration is the only solution?

Comment: What's wrong with a forward declaration? This is why they exist...

Comment: You don't need the full definition of A at that point. You can just put `class A;` above it and it'll compile fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

if You don't want to place A before B, then forward declaration is the only solution in that case (if You don't want to change definition of B - see Zac Howland answer for other ideas that change B). There is nothing wrong with that. Somehow, methods from B needs to know what A is (in that case it is a class). Either, compiler will figure it out by finding A definition or You will help the compiler with forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Any name shall be declared before its using. If you do not like the following code

```
class A;

class B
{
    public:
    void set_classA_val( A &b);
};
```

then you can use elaborated type name in the parameter declaration of member function set_classA_val

```
class B
{
    public:
    void set_classA_val( class A &b);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, but without more information about your goals, it is hard to tell you which is the best.  Forward declaration, move the definition of `A`, and making `B` a template class are some of the options.  Presuming you are familiar with the 2 former, the latter would look something like:

```
template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    set_value(T& t);
};
```

And you would declare it for use using:

```
B<A> ba;
```

As jrok mentioned, you can also make the function itself a template - but the use would depend on how `B` is using the parameter (e.g. if the type is needed for other functions as well, it would probably be better to make the whole class utilize it).

Comment: @jrok Good point, That would work as well (depending on how `B` will be using its template parameter).